# How to transfer a column value from SQL Server to checked list box of another form using c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working on a windows forms application in which I want to transfer a column from a SQL Server database to checked listbox of another from.

My code is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    contextMenuStrip1.Show(button1, 0, button1.Height);
}

private void selectByPictureToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection Cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
    SqlDataAdapter D_a = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Picture From Add to Database", Cn);

    DataColumn dt = new DataColumn();

    PictureSelection frm2 = new PictureSelection("PictureListBox.Rows[0].Value.ToString()",dt);
    frm2.Show();

    this.Hide();
}
```

and the next form code is:

```
public partial class PictureSelection : Form
{
    public PictureSelection(string s)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PictureListBox.Text = s;
    }
}
```

I am not getting any runtime error but I don't have any value shown in my checked list. Please help.

Comment: have you tried debugging `selectByPictureToolStripMenuItem_Click` to see what is returned by your query? That doesn't look like a valid SQL query to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There don't need to be quotes on this line:

```
 PictureSelection frm2 = new PictureSelection("PictureListBox.Rows[0].Value.ToString()",dt);
```

The quotes mean that you are literally passing through the string "PictureListBox.Rows[0].Value.ToString()".

If you are adding items to a checked listbox you need to add the item to the Items collection of the listbox.(ref:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky821k3b(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
checkedListBox.Items.Add("Bananan Cream Pie", CheckState.Checked);
```

What is the name of the table you are querying 
is it Add To Database? If it is and it has spaces in the name you have to enclose it in brackets like so [Add To Database].